# Android passing value why null?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm quite new to android programming.. and i have this problem.. i want to pass a value, but the result is null.. i wonder why is that so.. can anyone help me? thanks in advance. my code is something like this..

Manager.java

```
String prize="5";
Intent i = new Intent(Manager.this, Shop.class);
i.putExtra("Key", prize);
startActivity(i);
```

Shop.java

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
    String receive = myIntent.getStringExtra("Key");

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {               
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setText(receive);
    }

    else
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText("value is null");  //this is always the result
                                       //why is it null??
    }
```

Comment: first use this and check whether data is coming or not.
Toast.makeText(Shop.this, ""+receive,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @Kumar I tried Toast.makeText... but the value is still null

Comment: Hey please toast it just below this line
 String receive = myIntent.getStringExtra("Key");
Not inside if condition.

Comment: yes i put it below that line, but same result..

Comment: still u r facing the same issue

Comment: I tried the same code it's working fine man check it properly might me u r doing some silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

The function getExtras() returns a `Bundle` placed in the Intent using putExtras(b). Something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Manager.this, Shop.class);
i.putExtras(new Bundle());
startActivity(i);
```

Since you aren't using the putExtras function then getIntent().getExtras() returns null. You should do it like this:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
String receive = myIntent.getStringExtra("Key");

if (receive != null)
{               
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
tv.setText(receive);
}

else
{
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setText("value is null");  //this is always the result
                                   //why is it null??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this you are trying to access different key what you have set

```
String value= "Your String";
// Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Test.class);
// sending data to new activity
i.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the next activity

```
Intent i = getIntent();
// getting attached intent data
String value= i.getStringExtra("value");
// displaying selected product name
txtProduct.setText(value);
```

Comment: i tried this. but nothing happened to my textview. i added toast and the value is null. why is it like that?

Comment: @user2599219 have u seen this url http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Comment: even I got the solution of my problem from this URL hope u get u luck

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY");
```

May be it should do it.